# Updating a dialog with ajax of primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have 2 dialogs. Dialog(list) and Dialog(create). On dialog list I have a `<p:dataTable/>` that contain values that are inserted of Dialog(create). 
Dialog list, open Dialog create to insert values.

What I want is after insert values in dialog(create) automatically dialog(list) refresh with values inserted.

Looking for a solution, I found any suggestions to use `update` of `<p:commandButton/>` with ajax of primefaces. I am trying this but still haven't success.

How I can do update dialog(list) after insert values at dialog(create) ?

here how I trying.

**Dialog(list)**

```
<p:dialog header="Turmas" id="TurmaViewDlg" widgetVar="TurmaViewDialog" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false">
    <h:form id="TurmaListForm">
        <p:panel id="display">
            <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{turmaMB.turmas}" var="turma" 
                                    paginator="true" 
                                    rows="5" 
                                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,30,40,50"
                                    selectionMode="single"
                                    selection="#{turmaMB.bean}"
                                    rowKey="#{turma.id}"                        
                                    liveScroll="true"
                                    > 
                    <p:column headerText="#">
                            <h:outputText value="#{turma.id}"/>         
                    </p:column> 
                    <p:column headerText="Turma">
                            <h:outputText value="#{turma.turma}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Ano">
                            <h:outputText value="#{turma.ano}" />
                    </p:column> 
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Novo" update=":TurmaCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('TurmaCreateDialog').show()"/>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>  

    <ui:include src="create.xhtml"/>
</p:dialog>
```

**Dialog(create)**

```
<p:dialog header="Cadastro de turma" id="TurmaCreateDlg" widgetVar="TurmaCreateDialog" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false">

    <h:form id="TurmaCreateForm">
        <p:growl id="growl" life="3000"/>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="display">
            <f:validateBean>            
                <p:outputLabel value="Turma"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{turmaMB.bean.turma}"                             
                             maxlength="50"
                             id="turmaId"
                             >                     
                </p:inputText>                

                <p:outputLabel value="Ano"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{turmaMB.bean.ano}"                            
                             maxlength="4"
                             id="anoId"
                             >                         
                    </p:inputText>   
            </f:validateBean>                           
        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{turmaMB.insert(turmaMB.bean)}" update="display,:TurmaListForm:datalist,growl">            
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
            </p:commandButton>            
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="TurmaCreateDialog.hide()"/>
        </p:panel>


    </h:form>            
</p:dialog>
```

**Managed bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TurmaMB {
    private Turma bean = new Turma();
    private GenericDAO<Turma> dao = new GenericDAO<Turma>(Turma.class);
    private List<Turma> turmas = null;

    public void insert(Turma t){        
        dao.insert(t);
        bean = new Turma();
    }



    public Turma getBean() {
        return bean;
    }



public List<Turma> getTurmas() {
    if(turmas == null){
        turmas = dao.findAll();
    }
    return turmas;
}
```

Comment: You tryed emptying (`turmas=null;`) your turmas List in the Managed Bean to force the dao reloading everything and the new Turma entry?

Comment: wow dude, I don't believe that I didn't think this before. I am thinking when I do execute update of p:commandButton does get new list of database, but. I was thinking when I do execute update of p:commandButton its get new list of database, but. if I add object in list works also. thanks a lot. !

Comment: Glad I could help.  See my answer for another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and Ajax doesn't seems to be the problem.  The problem originates from your turmas List which is populated once : when turmas is accessed for the very first time.

So you have two options.

- clearing the turmas list with `turmas=null` and therefore force the dao to reload everything on the first call to `getTurmas()`.
- add the new turma entity to the turmas list.

Of course the first option is going to generate more traffic on the database.  The second option spare the database but you somewhat have an older copy of all the data.

So basically any of these solutions should solve your problem :

Option 1:

```
public void insert(Turma t){      
   dao.insert(t);
   turmas = null;
   bean = new Turma();
}
```

Option 2:

```
public void insert(Turma t){      
   dao.insert(t);
   turmas.add(t);
   bean = new Turma();
}
```